# How can you improve Face ID

Tags: ios, ipad, face-id

Face ID fails to recognize me 90% of the time on iPad Pro.

How do I know why it fails. What can I do to make it work?

I have read and done everything that's mentioned in Apple Support document, [If Face ID isn't working on your iPhone or iPad Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208114).

How, at least immediately after saving a Face ID scan can I check that it works, i.e. test Face ID say 10 times.

Now it seems to unlock from wake-up and is working about half of the time and in apps e.g. App Store not working at all - How can I keep retrying so it learns?

have just got a useful message from an app - saying that Face ID had failed 5 times so I need to reenter the apps password.

Comment: Have you tried re-registering your face

Comment: Have you tried it with someone else's face to see if it's just you?

Comment: @DManokhin That is Apple Doc's point 7 so yes

Comment: @fsb no - and I don't have anyone near - it works sometimes - e.g. just now twice in a row

Comment: I don't have any problem and it even recognizes me with/without glasses, hats, etc.  If it's still under warranty you should take it back to have it replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was the distance between face and ipad. Apple says 10-20 inches. I need it to be more than 20 inches to get 60% working on wakeup which is difficult when I can only read the message to use Face Id from less than 10 inches